# Can't click any the pop-up 1-click Google Play in-app purchase panel

Tags: google-play-store, in-app-purchase

In a game, I tried to make an in-game purchase but I can't click on the pop-up at all. Some features on google play error out as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe some of the issues like this are due to screen overlays. In my case it was the Twilight app (makes your screen red around bedtime).